# htm audio not playing on mobile phone

Tags: html, audio

I have the below code, it works well on my laptop, but the sound doesn't play on load on my mobile phone. What might be wrong?

```
<audio id="foobar" src="yoursample.ogg" preload="auto">
```

Set it hidden via CSS:

```
#foobar { display: none }
```

On the any JavaScript event handler play the audio:

```
var sample = document.getElementById("foobar");
sample.play();
```

Comment: In which browser you are trying to play the file?

Comment: What audio formats will the iPhone play/support? - Unfortunately, Ogg Vorbis didn't make the list. - http://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/9739

Answer (score 0):

Add an mp3 version of your audio file to make it compatible with all browsers.

```
<audio id="foobar" preload="auto">
  <source src="yoursample.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="yoursample.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```